# MySQL order by value1 unless value1 < 0, then order by value2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a script that runs 2 rather slow SQL queries that are almost identical. One selects from the database records that are supposed to be "featured" on a page, i.e. they come first. Another selects from the database the regular records. Each query takes approximately 0.3 seconds, and since both run at the same time, I lose 0.6 seconds on them. So I was wondering if it would be possible to combine these queries. Here is what they look like:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE [other where conditions] AND featured>=$timestamp ORDER BY featured DESC

SELECT * FROM records WHERE [other where conditions] AND featured<$timestamp ORDER BY created DESC
```

What I have labeled [other where conditions] is identical in both cases. So what I essentially need to do is:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE [other where conditions] ORDER BY featured DESC UNLESS featured < $timestamp, created DESC
```

Except I don't know how to tell MySQL "ORDER BY ... UNLESS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `order by` alone:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE [other where conditions]
ORDER BY (case when features >= $timestamp then featured else $timestamp end) DESC,
         created desc;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for my case because I sometimes need to sort created asc. With the order by if(), I can only go in the same direction with both sorting methods.

Comment: Isn't the AND in this answer wrong? With this query you will only get results where featured  is >= $timestamp to begin with.

Comment: @para . . . Good catch.  Removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html) for this.

```
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE [other where conditions]
ORDER BY IF(featured >= $timestamp, featured, created) DESC
```

Comment: Now what if I need to sort by featured DESC and created ASC? (This sometimes occurs)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, code is something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM records 
    WHERE [other where conditions] 
ORDER BY 
    IF(featured < $timestamp, created, featured) DESC
```

And php version will be something like this:

```php
$timestamp = now();
$SQLCond = "id = 4";
$SQLLimit = "LIMIT 0, 100";
$SQLMask = "SELECT * FROM records where " . $SQLCond . " ORDER BY IF(featured < " . mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp) . ", created, featured) DESC " . $SQLLimit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a featured flag in the rows returned like so:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN featured>=$timestamp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `featuredRecord`, *
FROM records
WHERE [other where conditions]
ORDER BY featured DESC
```

The first record should be featured records and the rest are regular records.

Comment: I assume you meant to `ORDER BY featuredRecord`?

Comment: Looked like the featured field was a date/time so it should have been okay. Featured Records in this case appear to be defined by their newness and should appear first.